# How to disable specific rule in FSharpLint?

Tags: build, f#

I created Settings.FSharpLint and I want to suppress `IdentifiersMustNotContainUnderscores` rule

Is it possible to disable only one rule?

Example (Doesn't work):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FSharpLintSettings>
  <Analysers>
    <NameConventions>
      <IdentifiersMustNotContainUnderscores>
        <Enabled>False</Enabled>
      </IdentifiersMustNotContainUnderscores>
    </NameConventions>
  </Analysers>
</FSharpLintSettings>
```

I tried this and it worked well (But it's for all NameConventions rules):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FSharpLintSettings>
  <Analysers>
    <NameConventions>
       <Enabled>False</Enabled>
     </NameConventions>
  </Analysers>
</FSharpLintSettings>
```

Comment: If you tried to do it and it worked well, then what's your question?

Comment: you can certainly post an answer to your own questions and even accept it. that's easier to read.

Comment: No. I want to disable only one rule, not all. Only 'IdentifiersMustNotContainUnderscores'. I made mistake in question, sorry :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `IdentifiersMustNotContainUnderscores` element needs to be nested inside a [`Rules` element](https://github.com/fsprojects/FSharpLint/blob/master/ConfigurationSchema.xsd#L58), try:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FSharpLintSettings>
  <Analysers>
    <NameConventions>
      <Rules>
        <IdentifiersMustNotContainUnderscores>
          <Enabled>False</Enabled>
        </IdentifiersMustNotContainUnderscores>
      </Rules>
    </NameConventions>
  </Analysers>
</FSharpLintSettings>
```

Comment: great, no problem :)

Comment: Could you please have a look to my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57240886/fsharplint-how-to-use-the-rule-interfacenamesmustbeginwithi-in-suppressmessag