# FSharpLint, how to use the rule "InterfaceNamesMustBeginWithI" in SuppressMessageAttribute?

Tags: visual-studio-code, f#

```
[<SuppressMessage("NameConventions","InterfaceNamesMustBeginWithI")>] //No effect
[<SuppressMessage("NameConventions","InterfaceNames")>] //It's working
module Test=
    type [<AllowNullLiteral>] MutationEvent =
        abstract attrChange: float with get, set
        ...
```

Also, failed to search source code about "InterfaceNamesMustBeginWithI".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the rule is `InterfaceNames`, so you can suppress it thus:

```
[<SuppressMessage("","InterfaceNames")>]
module Test =
    ...
```

Also note that the first argument to `SuppressMessage` is not used by fsharplint, so it can be anything (although not `null`, strangely enough!)

There are pointers to `InterfaceNamesMustBeginWithI` in the documentation, but this is not correct.

Comment: So, it's unavailable for detailed controlling? For example, ignore interface-not-begin-with-i but notify interface-name-with-camel-case?